# "...but it looks an impossible task."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> Firefighters are working hard to stop the fire, **but it looks an
> impossible task**.

Hi. Is the emboldened part acceptable or will I need a few more words?

Comment: There are options worth considering, such as "it seems an impossible task" and "it looks like an impossible task", and even "it looks impossible".

Comment: It's correct, but quite formal or old fashioned. If you want to sound more current or less formal, consider, "...it looks *like* an impossible task."